# Rails inclusion validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, inclusion

I'm struggling with the following inclusion validation,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :language

  validates :language, :presence => true, :inclusion => { :in => I18n.available_locales.join(' ')}
end
```

If I run this in the console,

```
u = User.new
u.valid?
```

then I get a `TypeError: can't convert nil into String` in the `include?` method of `active_model/validations/inclusion.rb`.

However, if I change the validation line to,

```
validates :language, :presence => true, :inclusion => { :in => %(en fr es)}
```

then the validation works as expected. It is invalid if language is either nil or not one of the entries in the list as you would expect and there is no crashing.

I've stepped through the code to verify that it is generating the inclusion list okay, which it is. So why does it crash? Shouldn't the presence validation pick up the problem and prevent any further validation? And why does it crash when I generate the list as opposed to hardcoding the values?

I even tried using the proc form of `:in` to see if that made any difference, which it didn't. But then I didn't really expect that to be needed because I only want to generate the list once when the app loads anyway since I18n.available_locales will never change during the execution of the app.

UPDATE:
I had an idea and tested the following code,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :language

  validates :language, :presence => true, :inclusion => { :in => ['en','fr','es'].join(' ') }
end
```

This code also generates the same error, so the problem is not with I18n or anything like that. It has to do with a difference between `%(en fr es)` and `['en','fr','es'].join(' ')`.

Comment: `%(en fr es) => "en fr es"` and `%w(en fr es) => ["en", "fr", "es"]`. `join` creates an array too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason your second condition works is that `#include?` is defined for the String class:

```
> "qwertyuiop".include? "tyu"
true
```

so if you validate inclusion in `%(en fr es)` (which is exactly `"en fr es"`) a value `"n f"` would pass the validation.

You have to use the array (either as literal `[]` or as words `%w()`). If you want to use I18n.available_locales be sure to convert them to strings

```
validates :language, :inclusion => { :in => I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s) }
```

I can't reproduce your error, but the `:presence` validation is useless, as the `:inclusion` already checks for the value to be in the list.

Answer (score 5):

You should pass an array into the `inclusion` validation, not a string. So in your example with `%(en fr es)` if you use `%w(en fr es)` it works fine.